# React Native app stuck on white screen on launch

Tags: react-native

I am using RN version 0.60 and My app is stuck in white screen without getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on debug mode. If it still exists,there is problem in your code or setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with gradle. After updating it to latest version everything working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The bundles might be loading at that time. Have a look at your terminal any errors might be thrown there.